# Why a div with float: right does not respect the margin of the hr tag below?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm using twitter-bootstrap framework and I'm trying to put a form-control with some text aligned to the right and some text aligned the the left (all in the same line).

Here is the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/2gu29/3/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="inlineb">Hello</div>
<div class="floatr inlineb">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inlineb"> cm
</div>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello stackoverflow</button>
```

**CSS**

```
hr {
    margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    border-color: red;
}
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100px;
}
.floatr {
    float: right;
}
.inlineb {
    display: inline;
}
```

But, as you see, the div which contains the input above the `hr` tag, does not respect the margin setted to the hr in the css (margin-top: 30px) if I use `float: right`. But if I don't use this property, it respect it. see it: **http://jsfiddle.net/2gu29/9/**

Why my solution does not work? Could you give me an exmplanation, please? Do you have another alternative to do it?

Any tip, advice or help will be appreciated, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

If you read this line from [MDN Float Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) you can understand that whenever we apply `float` property to any element, it is taken out from normal flow of the page.

Hence, margin is getting calculated from the **Hello** word instead of floated element.

**Solution**

Wrap the divs `inlineb and floatr` in another div and you should be fine. Checkout this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gu29/14/)**

**Updated Code**

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="inlineb">Hello</div>
  <div class="floatr inlineb">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inlineb" /> cm
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello stackoverflow</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! But the container class adds padding, and I dont want it. What  property of the container fix the issue? Do you have any alternative? What about the other solutions posted, is there any reason to don't use them?

Comment: We just need to increase the height of the container/wrapper So adding container class on div in bootstrap adds the properties `.container:after{ display:table; content: ' ', clear: both; }` So this content is using some space and hence container height got increased and you could see the effect. Alternately, set some height on the wrapper div. Note: Wrapper div is same as container div.

Comment: Alternately, you can give another class name to container div as well like `<div class="container wrapper"> ... </div>` and over-ride the padding on wrapper class.

Answer (score 7):

This is always a problem with floated element and inline element. If you want to fix this issue then you need to add `display:inline-block and width:100%` in hr tag.
Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gu29/12/)

Comment: Thanks! interesting! Could you give me a little explanation, please?

Comment: @Viken I like this apporach but could not understand how this is solving the problem..Tricky ;)

Comment: Margin was calculated between Hello word and hr tag because both are inline elements. Now button on right is floated element so If you want hr margin to be calculated from button you should make hr tag to block or floated element. and "display:inline-block" does that or even you can use "float:left;" as well.

Answer (score 1):

@blunderboy has already explained what the problem is. My answer is just an alternate solution, which I have floated the left element and aligned the input to the right, therefore it still has height.

**HTML**

```
<div class="floatl">Hello</div>
<div class="rightinput">
    <input type="text" class="form-control inlineb"/> cm
</div>
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Hello stackoverflow</button>
```

**CSS**

```
hr {
    margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    border-color: red;
}
body {
    padding: 30px;
}
.form-control {
    width: 100px;
}
.floatl {
    float: left;
}
.inlineb {
    display: inline;
}
.rightinput {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Yes, as it doesn't use anything apart from text alignment and floating. This should work in all browsers going right back the first versions of browsers that supported CSS1.